# Identifying the last element

Tags: css

How could I find the last child element using css and here is my code.

```
<div class="leftelement"></div>
<div class="rightelement"></div>
<div class="leftelement"></div>
<div class="rightelement"></div>
<div class="leftelement"></div> <!-- this element -->
<div class="rightelement"></div>
```

I tried the below method and its not working for me.Can any one help me out. I don't want using nth-child because sometimes the count of element may increase

`.leftelement:last-of-type` and `.leftelement:last-child` is not working

Comment: you want this with CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately with `class` its not possible via **last-of-type**.

Comment: Its Possible @Manwal Please have a look

Comment: You've got to respond to comments/answers if you want a solution. That aside, do your elements follow a specific pattern? That is, will there always be a `.rightelement` following a `.leftelement`? Do they always get added in pairs (or) is it possible for `.leftelement` alone to be present?

Comment: you dont want to try jquery?

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to use css selector? You should edit your tag then.

You could use jQuery `last()` function.

> **.last()**
>
> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the final one in the set.

```js
$('.wow').last().css('color','blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wow">wow
</div>
<div class="lol">EOOOW
</div>
<div class="wow">HEYY
</div>
<div class="lol">LOL
</div>
```

Comment: OP has not mentioned `jquery` or not added tag.

Comment: But he said he doesn't wan't to use css : "i dnt want using nth-child". I figured his html will change dynamically. So he doesn't want to hardcode some css selector. ( Like Tushar did). Which means the only solution is using JS.

Comment: @Paran0a: What I feel OP meant by *I don't want using nth-child* is that they didn't want a `:nth-child(5)` selector because the no. of elements could increase/decrease. They obviously didn't mean *don't want to use CSS*. Otherwise, they wouldn't have tagged it with CSS.

Comment: @Harry Well you can't use nth-of-type with classes , and he doesn't want to use nth-child. I got the feeling that his content will be dynamic. Meaning there's no way to get a proper selector in that case.

Comment: @Paran0a What if the element he is trying to select is always the second last element? We don't have any clarity on that yet. Their aversion to using `nth-child` might be that the second last element might be 4th or 8th or 24th but when you use `nth-last-child` the param would always be 2.

Comment: @Harry I agree, but at this point we're just wasting our time trying to read OP's mind.

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately the OP seems to have stopped responding.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>

div:last-child {
  color: red
}
```

this is de code pen http://codepen.io/yeion7/pen/gPXvNN

Comment: this is not what he asked for,

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:nth-last-of-type(n)` for this:

```
div:nth-last-of-type(2){
  color:red;
}
```

Increasing the number of elements won't matter as long as the element you want to pick is the one before the last.

**Note:** This will work if your elements are always structured as one `.leftelement` and one `.rightelement`. You cannot select the last `.leftelement` using only CSS.

**UPDATE:** If your content is dynamic and sometimes has `.leftelement` as the very last element and you still need to select this element, you can do this:

```
div:nth-last-of-type(2):not(.rightelement),
div:nth-last-of-type(2):not(.leftelement)+.leftelement{
  color:red;
}
```

Take a look at [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGOLOw).

Comment: @Raviteja: Judging by how the classes are named, I strongly doubt if a .`rightelement` would be followed by another `.rightelement`. But then again, all answerers should have waited for OP to clearly state the requirements.

Comment: @Raviteja I have added a note on the answer, but the OP does not state it should be the last `.leftelement`. The fact that `.leftelement:last-of-type` is tried as a solution does not mean it is the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible with `CSS` because we do not have `last-of-class` pseudo class yet, here is another frustrated user's [blog](http://discourse.wicg.io/t/add-last-of-class-pseudo-selector/582) about it.

thing is `last-of-type` and `last-child` work on the `element` name not on the 'class', nevertheless you can write css rules like

```
div.parent div.lastElement:last-of-type{
  color:blue; 
}
```

it will work totally fine if `div.leftElement` is last child `element of its kind`, [working fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/5h64gpc1/).

if your `.lastElement` is last kid of the `classname` but we have another `div` after that, it will fail. [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/12aqgfLu/)

if you have '.lastElement' on various `elements`, all then lasts will get styled. [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/punkhaa/L4xpcpsb/)

> Juice is that, we need pseudo CSS class something like `last-of-class` but we do not have that yet.